# php microseconds

Tags: php, datetime

I'm using
`echo date('H:i:s')." this step time\n";`
 in order to know how much time needs for each function in order to be executed.

How can I know the time with microseconds also?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to add, there's PHP's [microtime()](http://www.php.net/microtime) function, which can be used like this:

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

//do stuff here

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "It took $time seconds\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
u  Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2)
```

Take a look at http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for more information.

Comment: I have tried with `date('H:i:s.u')` but I always get 000000 as microseconds.

Comment: The format specifier 'u' doesn't work with date function, even in PHP 5.4.21. You need to write a wrapper to make it work. I use this: https://gist.github.com/m-manu/6248802

Comment: Even when I use the suggested DateTime() with ->format() in order to get the 'u' parameter, I still get 000000 on PHP 5.3.2. So, this functionality must not be working properly even up to that PHP version. One may have to use Manu's workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'u' marker in the format for milliseconds.