# Microseconds in PHP

Tags: php, timestamp

I'm accessing an API that requires a timestamp to be in microseconds, I can print the value and it works it prints this:

```
1295308800
```

So I figured I can multiply this by 1000 and then print this but when I print the query before I send it (using CURL) it prints this:

```
1.2953088E+12
```

Can I use a different variable type or something?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you printing the value? `echo time() * 1000` works fine for me and prints a normal integer.

Comment: @Pete: The first one is a timestamp in seconds right? If so, conversion from seconds to microseconds is `s*10^6` (`s*1000000`) not `s*1000`, the latter is to milliseconds.

Comment: @netcoder: interesting, the timestamps that are returned have only 3 additional digits so perhaps its not really microseconds, but I do need to print it 1295308800 as 13 digits not 10

Comment: @Pete: If it's 3 digits more, then it's milliseconds, not microseconds.

Comment: How does this API define the "timestamp"? What is it relative to? Are we talking about microseconds since the Unix Epoch? -- Edit: Do you have any documentation that we can reference on this API? Sounds like they may not be clearly describing what the expected input is.

Comment: @casablanca: Yes for some reason time() *1000 is working but when I put 1295308800 into a var called date and then echo $date*1000; it doesn't seem to work, very odd

Comment: I think most timestamps are Unix Epoch. @Pete: read my post

Comment: @Pete Herbert Penito: It works for me even if I put it in a variable. Are you sure you aren't modifying the value in any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sending the value in a way that PHP converts it to its exponent syntax (i.e. 1.2953088E+12) there's a nifty trick you can do using `printf` or `sprintf` in order to get the full number):

```
php -r '$date = 12434613435134661234; echo $date;'
1.2434613435135E+19

php -r '$date = 12434613435134661234; printf("%.0f", $date);'
12434613435134660608
```

You can then use `sprintf` to just assign that number to a variable (as a string) and pass that into the remote API.

Note the lack of accuracy from converting the floating point number, though.

**Edit**:

I also want to point out that PHP's unsigned decimal numbers appear to be accurate up to 19 places. So, this returns the correct value:

```
php -r '$date = 6243461343513466123; printf("%u", $date);'
6243461343513466123
```

When expressing that same value as a float, it loses its precision:

```
php -r '$date = 6243461343513466123; printf("%.0f", $date);'
6243461343513465856
```

Comment: If anybody in the future has this problem this will work, first you get the normal integer (10 chars) call it $date then you can do this: $date = sprintf("%.0f", ($date*1000));

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built-in `microtime()` function...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, this may be of use to you.

Here is a StackOverflow post regarding microtime

[php microseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772917/php-microseconds)

If you're looking for microseconds of a specific timestamp, then check out the `u` Format Character here: http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php